How do I prove this in symbolic logic if the premise is just a tautology?
I'm working on some proofs in symbolic logic and I pretty much get it, but I'm having an issue with the last one. Usually the premise sets up the proof and I can walk through it, but this one just starts with a tautology. I may be overthinking it, but I'm not even sure where to start.
⊤ ⊢ ∃x(D(x) → ∀yD(y))
I kinda get the second statement: "There exists an x such that if D(x) then for all y, D(y)." I think it's saying that if D is true for one element, then it is true for all other elements, but how does a tautology prove this? Or I guess a better phrasing is how can I structure this into a proof?

To prove $p \implies q$, use its equivalence to $\neg p \vee q$, and then just prove $q$.  With that approach, it doesn’t even matter what $p$ is.

In this case, $q$ is a reasonably famous “paradox” (not really a paradox, of course).  Either $D$ is always true, or it isn’t.  If it isn’t, then there’s some particular $x$ such that $D(x)$ is false, and so $D(x)$ implies anything.

This is the Drinker Paradox.

I'm guessing the author really wanted you to prove this tautology. To do this, you first need to somehow assume the existence of one object $x$. Then consider two cases: Either $\forall x: D(x)$ is true or it is false. In both cases, prove that the above tautology is true.

How are you supposed to prove this?  Using a formal derivation? Using formal semantics?  Truth tree? Resolution? Etc.

You can prove it quite easily using a form of natural deduction. I was able to do so in 24 lines as outlined above. (Formal proof available on request.)

Either by contradiction or starting from another tautology, like Excluded Middle.
